# How to make dependency auto-install in pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, pyproject.toml

## Description

I have new Python project containing 1 package with 1 dependency. I uploaded the package to PyPI (test) and when trying to install it using pip I get errors. However, if I install the package on which the project is depending I can install my package without issues.

## pyproject.toml

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools >= 61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "mediagrab"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [{ name = "mrprikol", email = "prikolus@proton.me" }]
description = "Python CLI for downloading videos from YouTube"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.11"
dependencies = ["pytube==15.0"]
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]
license = { file = "LICENSE" }
keywords = ["python", "cli"]

[project.urls]
Repository = "https://github.com/mrprikol/mediagrab"

[project.scripts]
mediagrab = "mediagrab.__main__:main"
```

Command that I use to download my package: `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/mediagrab`

My goal is to have ability to install the package without installing the dependencies manually. How can I achieve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+test.pypi.org

Comment: `pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple`. `extra-index-url` for `pypi.org` is a must here.